# Experiment to prove that dualism is true

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, dualism, physicalism

To prove experimentally that dualism is true, the dualist would need to show that:

Let be a person in physical state A at some instant t1 with conscious experience X.

Now, in another instant t2, the same person is again in physical state A, but now has conscious experience B.

This would prove that the mental doesn't depends on the physical, since two exactly physical states entailed different conscious experience.

Would this experiment prove that dualism is true?

Comment: That's not an experiment. There is no way to measure "physical state" in its entirety, and no way at all to compare "conscious experiences". Dualism, materialism, idealism are not scientific claims that can be proved or disproved experimentally at all, philosophy is not science. They stand or fall on how well they organize our views as a whole, experiments being only a small and inconclusive part of it.

Comment: @Conifold It is conceivable that, say, a Kardashev II or III civilization could measure and arrange the physical state of a brain down to the atom.  They would be limited in this by the uncertainty principle, but it could be possible to get very close to setting up the same state twice.

Comment: @Conifold I think I wanted to express a thought experiment.

Comment: @causative Why stop at atoms? Perhaps, "consciousness" supervenes on some sort of quantum gravity effects in microtubules, as Penrose suggests. And even if they could clone those (disregarding uncertainty) they still can't be sure they got it all the same, unless they have divine omniscience. The point is that experimental setups always make background assumptions and allowances, and those always create loopholes. Experiments can make metaphysical doctrines *implausible*, given the totality of other beliefs, but they neither decide them on their own, nor conclusively.

Comment: This is not even a thought experiment, just a rephrasing of (one) definition of dualism.

Comment: Problem is nobody is twice in the same physical state. If only because during the second phase of the experiment the subject would remember the first phase.

Comment: @Conifold The microtubules are made of atoms (although Penrose's case is very weak anyway).  Atom-scale construction would be sufficient to replicate the microtubules.  There is a lower limit on how far we can go - it is theoretically feasible to place atoms at atom-scales, and in fact humans can do this to some extent, but if you get too small the uncertainty principle starts kicking your butt, and we can't be sure even a Kardashev III civ would be able to overcome that; it may truly be a fundamental physical limitation.  But atom-scale placement is plausible for a Kardashev III.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, scientific experiments cannot ever give 100% certainty, just strong evidence.  Nothing can give 100% certainty.

Comment: @causative It's not that experiments cannot give 100% certainty, it's that they are unsuitable to judge metaphysical paradigms. Those are shells needed to set up experiments and make sense of their "certainty" to begin with.

Comment: @Conifold Some would say that if a metaphysical paradigm makes no empirical difference, then it makes no difference.  What sense is there in believing in a theory completely disconnected from what we can observe?  (By the way, mathematical claims can be checked empirically; "Does this proof-checking program say this proof is OK?" is an empirical question.)

Comment: @causative There is a wide space between "decided by individual experiments" and "completely disconnected from what we can observe" (and from what we do with it, which is far broader and more salient).  Large swaths of observations and experiments channeled into high level generalizations through epistemic and pragmatic choices have a cumulative effect, but that's far removed from testing dualism by experiments.

Comment: @Conifold if one set of high level generalizations yields the same empirical results as another set of high level generalizations, then they are, for practical purposes, equivalent; it doesn't matter which you choose to work with.  (The choice in practice should be based on whichever is easier to work with, e.g. which set of generalizations proposes fewer unnecessary parts.)  If one set of generalizations yields a different empirical result from the other, then the dispute can in principle be settled by experiment.

Comment: @causative Pragmatic is much broader than empirical, and empirical equivalence is far from enough exactly *for practical purposes*. That's why we take special relativity over Lorentz's theory of aether. And that's why physicalism may be preferable to dualism, or vice versa, even though both are flexible enough to accommodate anything empirical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129409/discussion-between-causative-and-conifold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experiment is incompletely specified.  How would you measure the conscious experiences X and B?

Presumably you would have to *ask* the person what they experienced, and take their answer as fact.  But their reporting of a difference in experience is a *physical* difference; words, noises, are physical events.  So we find that the physical consequences of state A were different between times t1 and t2.

This difference in physical consequences could be the result of randomness in the setup of A, or inherent randomness in the laws of physics.

Or it could be the result of some mysterious non-physical influence - some soul guiding the person's behavior.

So, the experiment would still be inconclusive.

It would be more conclusive if you could also trace the entire physical chain of cause and effect that led from state A to the utterance "I experienced X" or "I experienced B."  If this chain of cause and effect is in both cases entirely within our understanding of physics, this would be evidence *against* dualism.  On the other hand, if mysterious things happen within this chain of cause and effect that do not fit within our understanding of physics, that could be evidence for dualism - or for a new breakthrough in physics.

Comment: Why "But their reporting of a difference in experience is a physical difference; " ?The experiments asserts that both persons had the same conscious experience.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 "The same conscious experience"?  But you said at t1 they experienced X and at t2 they experienced B.

Comment: Sorry, I meant same physical state, but you comment about reporting a different experience is a 'physical difference': in what ground?

Comment: @Carlitos_30 If the person says "I experienced X" then he is making sound waves - physical phenomena.  If the person says "I experienced B" then he is making different sound waves - different physical phenomena.  So the physical result of the experiment must be different; the same initial state A did not always lead to the same physical result.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks.